# Find $\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{2^x-3^x}{3^x+4^x}\right)$

Tags: limits

$$\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{2^x-3^x}{3^x+4^x}\right)$$

When substituting, it has the form

$$\frac {\infty-\infty}{\infty+\infty}$$

I think it has to do with L'Hopital rule, But I couldn't put in an acceptable form $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\dfrac{ 0}0$

I think also, since the numerator is a difference and the denominator is addition, the limit will go to zero? Is this "rough way" useful?

Comment: your rough way isn't useful . For example if you had $2^x-4^x$ in the numerator, and $3^x+4^x$ in the denominator, the the limit would be $-1$ and not $0$.

Comment: The more useful "rough way" is that the $4^x$ in the denominator will dominate as $x$ grows.

Comment: $2^x - 3^x \operatorname*{\sim}_{x\to\infty} -3^x$, $3^x + 4^x \operatorname*{\sim}_{x\to\infty} 4^x$, so $\frac{2^x - 3^x}{3^x + 4^x}\operatorname*{\sim}_{x\to\infty} \frac{- 3^x}{4^x} = -\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general principle that I recommend is to divide top and bottom by the dominant term *of the denominator*.  In this case, $4^x$:
$$\frac{2^x-3^x}{3^x+4^x}=\frac{(\frac{2}{4})^x-(\frac{3}{4})^x}{(\frac{3}{4})^x-1}$$
Now, $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{2}{4})^x=0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{3}{4})^x=0$ so the limit is $$\frac{0-0}{0-1}=0$$

Comment: Very elegant!$\!\!\!\!$

Comment: @flawr: This is essentially same as my answer- which I had posted earlier, without making it so explicit, so that the OP has to think a bit.

Comment: @vadim123: It's clear that you don't understand what I wrote. It's ok that you are bounty hunting. My method is essentially same, and I wrote it befor you. Plus, you also have to evaluate two limits.

Comment: @vadim123: and now you have resorted to ugly downvoting. Sure- just shows your "class". Happy bounty hunting.

Answer (score 6):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{2^x-3^x}{3^x+4^x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(2/3)^x-1}{1+(4/3)^x}$$
$$=\frac{-1}{\infty}$$
$$=0$$

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is to factor out $3^x$ from the numerator, and $4^x$ from the denominator. Then $\bigg(\dfrac{3}{4}\bigg)^x \rightarrow 0$, and the rest of the fraction goes to $-1.$

Comment: Can the downvoter please leave a comment as to why the oldest answer was downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\frac{2^x-3^x}{3^x+4^x}=\frac{2^x}{3^x+4^x}-\frac{3^x}{3^x+4^x}$$ and consider each term separately.